# Moving volume between containers docker-composer

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have image A (some_laravel_project) and B (laravel_module). Image A is a Laravel project that looks like this.

- app
- modules

  - core
  - **Volume Image b here**
- config

As the list above suggests I want to share a volume from Image B in Image A using docker-compose. I want to access the files in container B.

This is the docker-compose I tried and didn't receive any errors creating those images in gitlab ci. I checked and the volume and its files are in stored in the module_user:latest container.

I think I made a mistake mounting the volume to some_laravel_project.

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel:
        image: some_laravel_project
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
          - /var/www/storage
          - userdata:/var/www/Modules

    user:
        image: laravel_module
        volumes:
          - userdata:/user
volumes:
    userdata:
    webroot:
```

Comment: What is the question you wanted answered?

Answer (score 1):

The method you used to share volumes across container in docker compose is the correct one. You can find this documented under [docker-compose volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

> if you want to reuse a volume across multiple services, then define a
>   named volume in the top-level volumes key. Use named volumes with
>   services,

In you case, the directory `/var/www/Modules` in `laravel` will have the same content as that in `/user` inside `user` service. You can verify that by going into the containers and checking each directoty by running;

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```